# Secondary Samba account cannot login to any shares

Tags: samba

Hello I'm a newbie to Linux and Samba and I am having trouble.

I have two users setup for logging into shares. The first user is "adam" and the second user is "sam".

Right now both users are allowed to login to the shares but when I try to login with the Sam account in Windows it tells me access is denied. The Adam account is able to login just fine to any share.

My share is located in /media/adam/4TB External Drive/Share2. I think the reason why Sam can't login is because the share is located under "adam" right? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you add "sam" to Samba? What does `sudo pdbedit -L` return?

Comment: What does `ls -l "/media/adam/4TB External Drive"` show?

Answer (score 0):

/media/adam was set up by the system in such a way ( an access control list ) that allows only adam passage to what is past it - in this case /4TB External Drive/Share2.

Regardless of the permissions on Share2 sam is not adam so access is denied.

There are a couple of ways around this problem. One way is to make sam look like adam by adding a line to /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
force user = adam
```

Where you put that line depends on how you set up your shares. If the share is defined in smb.conf then add it to the share definition. If you created the share from Nautilus just place the line under the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` line in smb.conf.

Either way after changing and saving the file restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```